# Android Volley - make POST with body and url parameters - getParams and getBody at the same time

Tags: android, post, get, android-volley, http-protocols

I have simple question which method to call on POST and which method to call on GET.

This is my simple Class:

```
public class CustomStringRequest extends Request<CustomNetworkResponse> {

private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Map<String, String> params;
private final String body;
private final Response.Listener<CustomNetworkResponse> listener;


public CustomStringRequest(int method,
                           String url,
                           Map<String, String> headers,
                           Map<String, String> params,
                           String body,
                           Response.Listener<CustomNetworkResponse> listener,
                           Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.headers = headers;
    this.params = params;
    this.body = body;
    this.listener = listener;
}



@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    return body != null ? body.getBytes() : null;
}
```

How can I use getParams() and getBody() at the same time? Is it possible, because when I check the super implementation I assume it's impossible.

I also commented out the method getBody() to see thats true.

Does that mean that i can't send POST with body and also url parameters? Are url parameters meant to be used for GET request?? Is this standard?

Comment: I think they are the same, since getParams called inside default getBody

Comment: @BNK, yes it seems like. It strange to me that there is no method to create UrlParametrs (well its deprecated... but still I don't believe that worked as UrlParams). Or am I missing something , and there is a method for that?

Comment: Do you mean the params in the url of GET requests?

Comment: No. In the POST. I need to make POST request with urlParams and body. I implemented this my self, for now. (Concatenation of url and urlParameters). If there is a methot that cover that concatenation it should work for get and post request, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure what your intentions with that! You can always append the url with your url parameters (If the parameters are that simple). And Then You can use `getParams()` or `getBody()` to pass more complex parameters.

I think the difference between those two is the encoding of your parameters while they travel through the network (though I am not 100% sure with this) but Yes. `getBody()` more secure.